# Compare words in a string without considering their positions?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, string-manipulation

In Postgres 9.6 I want to test whether two strings like these are considered the same:

`'this is a test number 01'`, `'number this is 01 a test'`

So I have created this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort_text(a text) RETURNS text AS $$
    declare t1 text;
    BEGIN
      select(array_to_string (
        array(
          select * from unnest(string_to_array(a, ' ')) order by 1), ' ')) into t1;
      RETURN t1;
    END;

$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

select (sort_text('this is a test number 01') = sort_text('number this is 01 a test'));
```

which actually looks to be working correctly.

I was wondering, is there any better way to do this?

---

`'this and this'` and `'and this'` are considered to be different.

All the strings are already stripped out (spaces and punctuation) and duplication is not a problem. String length 50 characters as max estimation.

Comment: I saw something similar to the answers given her, but shorter and different logic. Hers the link - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3254304/sql-compare-2-strings-without-considering-accents-and-other-stuff-%C3%AE%C4%83%C5%A3%C5%9F-iats

Comment: @BenSchmeltzer: That's an unrelated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a single SELECT in a plain SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strings_equivalent(a text, b text)
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$
   SELECT a1 = b1
   FROM  (
      SELECT string_agg(w, ' ') AS a1
      FROM  (
         SELECT w
         FROM   unnest(string_to_array(a, ' ')) w
         ORDER  BY w
         ) a1
      ) a2
   , (
      SELECT string_agg(w, ' ') AS b1
      FROM  (
         SELECT w
         FROM   unnest(string_to_array(b, ' ')) w
         ORDER  BY w
         ) b1
      ) b2
   WHERE  length(a) = length(b)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT FALSE
   LIMIT 1;  -- for clarity, not needed
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Call:

```
SELECT strings_equivalent('this is a test number 01', 'number this is 01 a test');
```

This is assuming:

- Duplicate words count like any other words
- Separator is a single space
- No leading or trailing spaces

The function returns NULL for any empty string or NULL input.

The `UNION ALL` construct is a shortcut to return `FALSE` immediately if the input strings don't have the same length and avoid more expensive processing. Related:

- [Return a value if no record is found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8098795/return-a-value-if-no-record-is-found/8098816#8098816)
- [SQL order by query results in any arbitrary (but reproducible) manner](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75876/sql-order-by-query-results-in-any-arbitrary-but-reproducible-manner/75905#75905)

`LIMIT 1` is not needed because the function only returns the first column of the *first row* anyway and ignores the rest if there are more rows.

`IMMUTABLE` (since the result never changes for the same input) helps performance with repeated evaluation and allows indexes on functional expressions.

You could use [`regexp_split_to_table(a, ' ')`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) instead of `unnest(string_to_array(a, ' '))`, but regular expression functions are typically more expensive. (You can cover more sophisticated separator characters with the regex, though, like `'\s+'` for any white space). Related:

- [How to preserve the original order of elements in an unnested array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27279/how-to-preserve-the-original-order-of-elements-in-an-unnested-array/27287#27287)

---

BTW, your simple function `sort_text()` looks good. But use [`string_agg()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE) instead of `array_to_string(ARRAY(...))` in a simple SQL function. No variable assignment needed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION sort_text(a text)
  RETURNS text AS
$$
   SELECT string_agg(w, ' ')   
   FROM  (
      SELECT w
      FROM   unnest(string_to_array(a, ' ')) w
      ORDER  BY 1
      ) sub
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: "NULL for any empty string or NULL input." Isn't it better to mark it as `STRICT`?

Comment: @EvanCarroll: Possibly. But I avoid `STRICT` whenever I can because it blocks function inlining.

Comment: @EvanCarroll: I dug up this old question, where we worked that out and rerun the test: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8455177/939860. Still applies in current Postgres.

Answer (score 2):

Update: combining the ideas of @Erwin Brandstetter (use a "single" SELECT), and a set operation, the following may also be a possibility:

```
create or replace function strings_equivalent(a text, b text) 
returns boolean as $$
select 
  case 
    when length(a) >= length(b) then ( 
      select count( exa1 ) from (
        select unnest( string_to_array( a, ' ' ) ) 
        except all
        select unnest( string_to_array( b, ' ' ) ) ) exa1 
      ) = 0
    when length(a) < length(b) then ( 
      select count( exa2 ) from (
        select unnest( string_to_array( b, ' ' ) ) 
        except all
        select unnest( string_to_array( a, ' ' ) ) ) exa2
      ) = 0
    else false
  end
$$ language sql immutable;
```

Testing:

```
select 
  strings_equivalent('s1 s2 s3','s5 s4 s3 s2 s1')       false1
, strings_equivalent('s1 s2 s3 s4 s5','s1 s3 s5 s2 s4') true1
, strings_equivalent('s1 s2 s3 s4 s5','s6 s7')          false2
, strings_equivalent('a b','b a')   true2
, strings_equivalent('a b','a z')   false3
, strings_equivalent('a z','z a')   true3
, strings_equivalent('a b','a z x') false4
, strings_equivalent('a','a')       true4
, strings_equivalent('a 1 b','a a 1 1 b b')    false5
, strings_equivalent('this is','this is this') false6
;
```

Output:

```
 false1 | true1 | false2 | true2 | false3 | true3 | false4 | true4 | false5 | false6 
--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+-------+--------+--------
 f      | t     | f      | t     | f      | t     | f      | t     | f      | f
(1 row)
```

Comment: The variable assignment does not work as you seem to assume. `unnest()` is a set-returning function, and only the first column of the first row is assigned to a `scalar` variable in a plpgsql assignment. Effectively, this only compares the first word and does not work as advertised. Try: `SELECT strings_equivalent('a b', 'a z')` ...

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: thanks for pointing this out.  It felt a bit "too simple" when I wrote the code - and I did not run enough tests, of course.  Thanks again.

Comment: Your new idea with a `FULL JOIN` is smart, but it fails for duplicate words. [See OP's comment.](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/175368/how-to-compare-words-in-a-string-without-considering-their-positions/175463#comment339644_175368). I guess you missed that because of a typo in your last test: should probably be `'a 1 b','a a 1 1 b b'`.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: Thanks for your comments! I just realised this when comparing your version and mine using a larger test table - I have learned a few things during this discussion.  I've not given up yet :-)

Answer (score 1):

I would use [`plperl`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plperl.html), but having seen the performance of [Erwin's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/175380/2639) I'm not sure that it matters much, both run in approximately the same time.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strings_equivalent_pl(a text, b text)
RETURNS bool AS
$func$
   my (%arg1, %arg2);
   $arg1{$_}++ for grep /\w/, split /\s+/, $_[0];
   $arg2{$_}++ for grep /\w/, split /\s+/, $_[1];

   return 0 if length %arg1 != length %arg2;

   foreach ( keys %arg1 ) {
     return 0 if $arg1{$_} != $arg2{$_};
   }
   return 1;
$func$
LANGUAGE plperl
STRICT IMMUTABLE;
```

In Perl, a hash is a list of key-value pairs. Here we

1. create two hashes that represent as keys your words and that represent the occurrences as values.
2. ensure that both hashes have the same length (amount of words)
3. ensure that both hash have the same words and the same amount of occurrences.

**Note we do use `\s` so we handle all space-chars regardless of the amount, and leading and trailing spaces do not matter (we `grep` to remove leading spaces).**

Answer (score 1):

There are several answers here. Lets test them all :o)

```
--drop table if exists t;
--drop function if exists strings_equivalent_erwin(text, text);
--drop function if exists strings_equivalent_stefan(text, text);
--drop function if exists strings_equivalent_evan(text, text);
--drop function if exists strings_equivalent_my(text, text);
create table t(x text);
insert into t select concat((random()*100)::int, ' ',(random()*100)::int, ' ',(random()*100)::int) from generate_series(1,500);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strings_equivalent_erwin(a text, b text)
  RETURNS bool AS
$func$
   SELECT a1 = b1
   FROM  (
      SELECT string_agg(w, ' ') AS a1
      FROM  (
         SELECT w
         FROM   unnest(string_to_array(a, ' ')) w
         ORDER  BY w
         ) a1
      ) a2
   , (
      SELECT string_agg(w, ' ') AS b1
      FROM  (
         SELECT w
         FROM   unnest(string_to_array(b, ' ')) w
         ORDER  BY w
         ) b1
      ) b2
   WHERE  length(a) = length(b)
   UNION ALL
   SELECT FALSE
   LIMIT 1;  -- for clarity, not needed
$func$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;

create or replace function strings_equivalent_stefan(a text, b text) 
returns boolean as $$
select 
  case 
    when length(a) >= length(b) then ( 
      select count( exa1 ) from (
        select unnest( string_to_array( a, ' ' ) ) 
        except all
        select unnest( string_to_array( b, ' ' ) ) ) exa1 
      ) = 0
    when length(a) < length(b) then ( 
      select count( exa2 ) from (
        select unnest( string_to_array( b, ' ' ) ) 
        except all
        select unnest( string_to_array( a, ' ' ) ) ) exa2
      ) = 0
    else false
  end
$$ language sql immutable;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION strings_equivalent_evan(a text, b text)
RETURNS bool AS
$func$
   my (%arg1, %arg2);
   $arg1{$_}++ for grep /\w/, split /\s+/, $_[0];
   $arg2{$_}++ for grep /\w/, split /\s+/, $_[1];

   return 0 if length %arg1 != length %arg2;

   foreach ( keys %arg1 ) {
     return 0 if $arg1{$_} != $arg2{$_};
   }
   return 1;
$func$
LANGUAGE plperl
STRICT IMMUTABLE;

create or replace function strings_equivalent_my(a text, b text) returns bool immutable language plpythonu as $$
  return sorted(a.split(' ')) == sorted(b.split(' '))
$$;
```

The most slow is the Stefan's variant. On my aged HW it is:

```
explain analyse select * from t as t1 join t as t2 on (strings_equivalent_stefan(t1.x, t2.x));
```

```
Execution time: 37323.874 ms
```

The accepted Erwin's case is faster a bit (but not much significant):

```
explain analyse select * from t as t1 join t as t2 on (strings_equivalent_erwin(t1.x, t2.x));
```

```
Execution time: 29939.032 ms
```

The Evan's variant is faster more then 2 times:

```
explain analyse select * from t as t1 join t as t2 on (strings_equivalent_evan(t1.x, t2.x));
```

```
Execution time: 13452.271 ms
```

But the winner is my lovely Python :o) (and it is also much more readable)

```
explain analyse select * from t as t1 join t as t2 on (strings_equivalent_my(t1.x, t2.x));
```

```
Execution time: 5818.160 ms
```

Good luck.

PS: To be honest, there is regex variant with removing whitespaces and case insensitive:

```
create or replace function strings_equivalent_my(a text, b text) returns bool immutable language plpythonu as $$
  import re
  return sorted(re.split('\s+', a.strip().lower())) == sorted(re.split('\s+', b.strip().lower()))
$$;
```

and it is much slower: `Execution time: 12127.945 ms` but it is still faster then Perl.

Comment: I really like your solution.  Smashing!  Thanks for sharing this with us.